# .Net 2 MVC 6 How to properly initialise and use List<Classname> in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, .net-2.0

**Model class**

```
using System;

namespace MySystem.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        private string username;
        private string age;

        public User()
        {            
        }

        public User(string username, string age)
        {
            this.username = username;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public string Username 
        {   
            get { return username; } 
            set { username = value; }
        }

        public string Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using System.Linq
@model List<MySystem.Models.User>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddWithHTMLHelperAndModel", 
"List<MySystem.Models.User>", FormMethod.Post))
{
   if (!Model.Any())
   {
      <label>Empty</label> // Model is void, why??
      @Model.Add(new User("Username1", "35"))// Returns error that void can't be changed to obj.
   }
   else 
   {
       <label>Model has content.</label>
   }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult AddWithHTMLHelperAndModel()
    {   
    List<User> usermodel = new List<User>();

                return View(usermodel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddWithHTMLHelperAndModel(List<User> user)
    {
        var updated_model = user;

        return View(updated_model);
   }
```

There appears to be an initialisation problem. No idea why. Before I was able to use the related model just with the reference to it in the beginning of the view (no separate initialisation required).

Also, if I try my User model without the view, just in "main", it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know how does *Model-Binder* works in MVC? You don't need to send `List<MySystem.Models.User>` as a parameter to your `Controller` instead you should specify the `Controller's Name` as second parameter of `Html.BeginForm`.

Comment: Not related, but your 2nd argument of `BeginForm()` makes no sense - that is for the name of the controller. But that code does not belong in a view - its the responsibility of your controller to populate the model and pass it to the view.

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddWithHTMLHelperAndModel", 
"List<MySystem.Models.User>", FormMethod.Post))` => `List<MySystem.Models.User>` should be substituted by controller class name, and you can use viewmodel to create `List<User>` property and pass it to controller action after submit.

Comment: @all: Thanks for the answers so far. The first string in BeginForm should point to the controller, the second one always pointed to the model and it worked before. Anyways without being able to create my List<> I am not even trying to submit anything yet... ;)

Comment: The first parameter never points to the controller (it the name of the action). And I suggest you study the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) because your code code never have worked despite what you claim

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with this:

```
@Model.Add(new User("Username1", "35"))
```

Resulting in this error message:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4rpD.png)

Removing the leading **"@"** works. The **good syntax** is:

**`Model.Add(new User { Username = "I am in the view!", Age = "15"});`**

I was mislead in believing that my Model was empty, since it seemed to go into the (!Model.Any()) part.

I hope this can save someone 2 Days of frustration...